# How to replace value with more than one attribute in config file in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a file called entlib.config like below:

```
<loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true"
  defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
<listeners >
  <add name="Email TraceListener" toAddress="axx.xxx@xxx.com" fromAddress="axx.xxx@xxx.com" subjectLineStarter="xxxxx " subjectLineEnder="" smtpServer="xxx.com" smtpPort="xxx" formatter="Text Formatter"
```

Now,in this file needs to replace  fromAddress, toAddress and subjectLineStarter attribute has a variables groups for azure pipeline... how to do this change ? can we do have an option to change any config file that has been created as xml to change more than one attribute ?

Comment: Is there any update  about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the vaules in **.config file with the variables in Variable group, you can try the following methods:

1.You can use the **XML variable substitution** option in the Azure App service deploy task or IIS deploy task.

[image]

For more detailed steps, refer to this doc: [XML variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution)

2.You can use PowerShell script to modify attributes in the config file.

Here is the PowerShell script sample:

```
$entlibConfig = 'path\entlib.config'

Function updateConfig($config) 
{ 
$doc = (Get-Content $config) -as [Xml]
$root = $doc.get_DocumentElement();
$activeConnection = $root.loggingConfiguration.listeners.SelectNodes("add"); #You need to define the correct location of the parameter
$activeConnection.SetAttribute("fromAddress", "$(fromAddress)");
$activeConnection.SetAttribute("toAddress ", "$(toAddress )“);
$activeConnection.SetAttribute("subjectLineStarter ", "$(subjectLineStarter )“);
$doc.Save($config)
} 

updateConfig($entlibConfig)
```

3.When you add the mark: `#{..}#` in entlib.config file, you can try to use the Replace Token task from [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Refer to the example in this ticket:[How to perform XML Element substitution in web.config using Replace Tokens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729738/how-to-perform-xml-element-substitution-in-web-config-using-replace-tokens/67767277#67767277)